# Help with our Validation Rule on Lead

Tags: validation-rule, administrator

we currently have a validation rule on Lead as follows:

```
AND(
    AND(
        $Profile.Name <>'B2BMA Integration User',
        $Profile.Name<>'System Administrator'
    ),
    OR(
        ISBLANK(Address),
        AND(
            ISBLANK(Phone),
            ISBLANK(MobilePhone)
        ),
        ISBLANK(FirstName)
    )
)
```

We would like to amend this so that a Lead CAN be created if the Lead Source = Live Chat AND the CreatedBy.UserType = "AutomatedProcess"

Currently we have amended the validation rule so that it now reads:

```
OR(
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL(CreatedBy.UserType, "AutomatedProcess"),
        NOT(ISPICKVAL(LeadSource ,'Live Chat')
    ),
    AND(
        AND(
            $Profile.Name <>'B2BMA Integration User',
            $Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator',
            $Profile.Name <> 'Marketing Integration'
        ),
        OR(
            ISBLANK(Address),
            AND(
                ISBLANK(Phone),
                ISBLANK(MobilePhone)
            ),
            ISBLANK(FirstName)
        )
    )
)
)
```

This is not working correctly and is allowing the user to create a Lead without the specified original fields. We have also tried the following rule which is still not functioning as expected.

```
AND(
    AND( 
        ISPICKVAL(CreatedBy.UserType, "AutomatedProcess"),
        NOT(ISPICKVAL(LeadSource ,'Live Chat')
    ),
    AND(
        AND(
            $Profile.Name <>'B2BMA Integration User',
            $Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator',
            $Profile.Name <> 'Marketing Integration'
        ),
        OR(
            ISBLANK(Address),
            AND(
                ISBLANK(Phone),
                ISBLANK(MobilePhone)
            ),
            ISBLANK(FirstName)
        )
    )
)
)
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to format this correctly? Thank you.

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  +1 for a properly formatted VR rule - so many new posters don't do this and you are to be commended

Comment: This did not work, thank you for the suggestion. When I amended my VR to the following - a Prospect is no longer created when a chat is initiated through digital engagement.           AND(OR(
NOT(ISPICKVAL(CreatedBy.UserType, "AutomatedProcess")),
NOT(ISPICKVAL(LeadSource ,'Live Chat'))
),
AND(
AND(
$Profile.Name <>'B2BMA Integration User',
$Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator',
$Profile.Name <> 'Marketing Integration'
),
OR(
ISBLANK(Address),
AND(
ISBLANK(Phone),
ISBLANK(MobilePhone)
),
ISBLANK(FirstName)
)
)
)

Comment: The initial format was allowing users to bypass validation rule and create a Lead without the specified fields (address, First Name, Phone) but was at least allowing me to create a Prospect through chat.

Answer (score 1):

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(CreatedBy.UserType, "AutomatedProcess"),
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(LeadSource ,'Live Chat')
),
```

Should be:

```
NOT(
  AND(
    ISPICKVAL(CreatedBy.UserType, "AutomatedProcess"),
    ISPICKVAL(LeadSource ,'Live Chat')
  )
),
```

Or, you can use:

```
OR(
  NOT(ISPICKVAL(CreatedBy.UserType, "AutomatedProcess")),
  NOT(ISPICKVAL(LeadSource ,'Live Chat'))
),
```

These are functionally equivalent through [de Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), which states that "NOT A AND NOT B" is the same as "NOT (A OR B)", and "NOT A OR NOT B" is the same as "NOT (A AND B)" (this formula is an example of the latter rule).

Remember: validation rules fire when the formula evaluates to true. In this case, you want this to evaluate to true when the user isn't the automated process and the lead source is not "live chat."

In either case, the top-level Boolean function should indeed be AND, not OR, as written in your final example.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation but that did not work. When I amend my VR to as follows: AND(OR(
NOT(ISPICKVAL(CreatedBy.UserType, "AutomatedProcess")),
NOT(ISPICKVAL(LeadSource ,'Live Chat'))
),
AND(
AND(
$Profile.Name <>'B2BMA Integration User',
$Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator',
$Profile.Name <> 'Marketing Integration'
),
OR(
ISBLANK(Address),
AND(
ISBLANK(Phone),
ISBLANK(MobilePhone)
),
ISBLANK(FirstName)
)
)
)

Comment: @user126057 - please use [edit] to amend you post with current version; comments are impossible to read for something this complex